# SharePoint 2013 Mandatory Column when Based on drop down on another column

Tags: validation, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 list where I need to log Issues.

One of my column is labelled `Issue Status`. Generally, I have REQUIRED field populated when the form is filed out and the `Issue Status`=OPEN or =PENDING.

But I want to make some columns REQUIRED and others OPTIONAL when someone selects `Issue Status`= DRAFT

Can this is done by Validation Setting in SharePoint? If so, what is the formula?

For example- `IF "Issue Status"= DRAFT then "Control ID" and "Impacted Business" Column is OPTIONAL and the rest is REQUIRED`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my test, if [Issue Status] is "DRAFT",  [Control ID] and [Affected Business] columns are optional, [Test], [Test2] and [Test3] columns are required

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Navigation to the list as a site admin

[image]

2.**List settings** >> **Validation settings**

[image]

3.On the Validation Settings page, please use the below Formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Test1])=TRUE,[Issue Status]="DRAFT"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Test2])=TRUE,[Issue Status]="DRAFT"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Test3])=TRUE,[Issue Status]="DRAFT"),FALSE,TRUE)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But will all other status options such as "Open" & "Pending" show that everything is required and NOT optional? All i want is when someone logs an issue as a draft they have a freedom not to fill all the required columns. For example, when an issue is saved as a draft they will fill only TWO of the required column but if the issue is set to " Open" they  will fill ALL the required column.

Comment: From your example, when status is open or pending "control id","Impacted business""test1" "test2" and "test3" is required and in the column setting they are all set to required

Comment: Also the formula did not work. I was getting error messages

Comment: Please use this formula: =IF(AND(ISBLANK([Column_A])=TRUE,[Issue Status]="DRAFT"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Column_B])=TRUE,[Issue Status]="DRAFT"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Column_C])=TRUE,[Issue Status]="DRAFT"),FALSE,TRUE))) Note: Please enter your Columns Name to replace Column_A, Column_B and Column_C

Comment: The formula did not error out but i dont think its working. so Basically 5 of my column are "required" and 3 are optional. I was testing to see if the "issue status =draft" the optional field is required by this formula. but it didn't work ;(. Any other suggestions?